# If else loop not adding valuing to variable using +=?

Tags: java, if-statement, matrix, sum

I have a 1D matrix with data and another with scores. I'm trying to loop across all of the elements in the data and find the element in the same position in the score matrix, and keep adding these values together during each loop. For some reason, my script keeps starting from `sum` = zero instead of retaining and adding to the sum from the previous loop. For the below example, I expect `sum` = 1 in the first loop, 3 after the second loop (since 1+2=3) and 6 after the third loop (3+3=6). Instead, sum just yields the last value retrieved from `scores`. What am I doing wrong here?

```
public static int calc_score( ) 
    {
        String [] dat = {"A", "B","C"};
        int [][] scores = new int [1][3];
        scores[0][0] = 1;
        scores[0][1] = 2;
        scores[0][2] = 3;
        
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < dat[0].length(); i++)
        {
            if (dat[i].equals("A")) {
                sum = sum + scores[i][0];
// scores[i][0] returns the expected value of 1 in the first loop
            }
                
            else if (dat[i].equals("B")) {
                sum = sum + scores[i][1];
            }
                
            else if (dat[i].equals("C")) {
                sum = sum + scores[i][2];
            }
                
            
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
        return sum;
        
        
    }
```

I tried modifying `sum = sum + scores[i][1];` to `sum+=scores[i][1]` but that doesn't fix this. I have to be missing something simple.

Comment: Rethink your abort condition `i < dat[0].length()` ...

Comment: scores[i][2] doesn't exist in your program, when i==2. This is when dat[i] == 'C'. Unless I've misunderstood something.

Answer (score 1):

Learn to debug. Add println statements, or use a debugger, and track, on paper if you prefer, what you think the program should do. Where the computer does something different from what you thought: Voila. You found a bug; there may be more.

If you can't figure out why something is happening, go back and re-check assumptions.

Had you done that here, for example, you might have eventually noticed: Huh, that for loop really is only running exactly once, that's bizarre. Eventually you'd check what `dat[0].length()` returns and then realized it returns, mysteriously, `1`, and perhaps then you'd have one of those slap yourself on the forehead moments: `dat[0]` refers to the first entry in the `dat` array, so, the string `"A"`. Then you ask that **string** about length, which dutifully returns `1`.

I assume you wanted `dat.length` instead.

Note that `scores[1][0]` is 0 too, you have more than one problem here.